# reading header of message phython

Tags: ros, rospy, headers, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi bellow is a link to the topic I am subscribing to

- [sensor_msgs/LaserScan](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html)

header header  # timestamp in the header is the acquisition time of the first ray in the scan.

compact message definition (partial)

```
std_msgs/Header header
float32 angle_min
float32 angle_max
```

How do you access the time_stamp in the header?
I know how to access other elements

def callback_lidar(data):

eg i would do angle = data.angle_min
ect

ps for some reason when i write questions/paste code all the spacing gets ignored...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54631/reading-header-of-message-phython/) by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 418 on 2013-02-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) on 2013-02-07**:
would it be time_scan = data.stg_msg.time

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-09**:
Use the code button (10101010) to display code nicely.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-29**:
Also, you can select a chunk of verbatim lines and press C-k to indent them all four spaces so they display correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming your message is in **msg**, the time stamp is: `msg.header.stamp`.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3